# How to write a better JS function - Input radio with tab box

Tags: javascript

I have written this function in JavaScript to show a text info box about the input radio is checked. It is not working very well. Can some one show me a better way?

I don't know why only 2 input works here, in my page all works good. But I'm sure that there is a better way to write the js function.

```js
document.getElementById('materiali').onclick = function(){myFunction()}; // click on div with input

function myFunction() {
 var materiales = document.getElementsByName('materiale'); // div that contains input
 var materiale_value;
 var materiale_valueName;

 for(var i = 0; i < materiales.length; i++){
   if(materiales[i].checked){
     materiale_value = i; // index obj input checked
     materiale_valueName = materiales[i].value; // value of the input checked
   }
 }

 var materialiText = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value].className; // Class that contains the relative input text selected
 
  var divNoShow = document.querySelectorAll('.text div'); // all div with text
 
  for (var j = 0; j < divNoShow.length; j++) {
  divNoShow[j].style.display = "none" // don't show all div with text
 }
 document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value].style.display = "block"; // show only the div with the class selectd by idex obj

}
```

```html
<div class="materiali" id="materiali">
  <p class="uppercase">Choose material</p>
  <input class="osb" type="radio" name="materiale" id="osb" value="osb">
   <label>OSB</label>
  <input class="fir" type="radio" name="materiale" id="fir" value="fir">
   <label>FIR</label>
  <input class="mdf" type="radio" name="materiale" id="mdf" value="mdf">
   <label>MDF</label>
  <input class="poplar" type="radio" name="materiale" id="poplar" value="poplar">
   <label>POPLAR</label>
</div>

<div class="text">
 <div class="osb" style="display:none">OSB Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
 <div class="fir" style="display:none">FIR Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
 <div class="mdf" style="display:none">MDF Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
 <div class="poplar" style="display:none">POPOLAR Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain in what ways this does "not work very well".

Comment: @ScottHunter, Only two input works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few simple changes will make it work better for you:

1. Use `divNoShow[materiale_value]` to make the selected item visible. It will only be the divs you want instead of extra text nodes.
2. Wrap the radio buttons with their labels, so that clicking the label will select the radio.
3. Return early if no radio is selected to avoid an error.

```js
document.getElementById('materiali').onclick = function(){myFunction()}; // click on div with input

function myFunction() {
    var materiales = document.getElementsByName('materiale'); // div that contains input
    var materiale_value;
    var materiale_valueName;

    for(var i = 0; i < materiales.length; i++){
        if(materiales[i].checked){
            materiale_value = i; // index obj input checked
            materiale_valueName = materiales[i].value; // value of the input checked
        }
    }
    var divNoShow = document.querySelectorAll('.text div'); // all div with text
 
    for (var j = 0; j < divNoShow.length; j++) {
        divNoShow[j].style.display = "none" // don't show all div with text
    }
    if(typeof materiale_value=="undefined") return;
    divNoShow[materiale_value].style.display = "block"; // show only the div with the class selectd by idex obj
}
```

```html
<div class="materiali" id="materiali">
    <p class="uppercase">Choose material</p>
    <label>
        <input class="osb" type="radio" name="materiale" id="osb" value="osb"> OSB
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="fir" type="radio" name="materiale" id="fir" value="fir"> FIR
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="mdf" type="radio" name="materiale" id="mdf" value="mdf"> MDF
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="poplar" type="radio" name="materiale" id="poplar" value="poplar"> POPLAR
    </label>
</div>

<div class="text">
    <div class="osb" style="display:none">OSB Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
    <div class="fir" style="display:none">FIR Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
    <div class="mdf" style="display:none">MDF Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
    <div class="poplar" style="display:none">POPOLAR Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, using `divNoShow [material_value]` is the kind of improvement I meant

Answer (score 1):

When you do `document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes`, the resulting array looks like that:

```
0: text
1: div.osb
2: text
3: div.fir
4: text
5: div.mdf
6: text
7: div.poplar
8: text
```

So you only need to change this line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value].style.display = "block";
```

To this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value*2+1].style.display = "block";
```

Final result:

```js
document.getElementById('materiali').onclick = function(){myFunction()}; // click on div with input

function myFunction() {
 var materiales = document.getElementsByName('materiale'); // div that contains input
 var materiale_value;
 var materiale_valueName;

 for(var i = 0; i < materiales.length; i++){
   if(materiales[i].checked){
     materiale_value = i; // index obj input checked
     materiale_valueName = materiales[i].value; // value of the input checked
   }
 }

 var materialiText = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value].className; // Class that contains the relative input text selected
 
  var divNoShow = document.querySelectorAll('.text div'); // all div with text
 
  for (var j = 0; j < divNoShow.length; j++) {
  divNoShow[j].style.display = "none" // don't show all div with text
 }
 document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value*2+1].style.display = "block"; // show only the div with the class selectd by idex obj
    //console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].childNodes[materiale_value]);
}
```

```html
<div class="materiali" id="materiali">
        <p class="uppercase">Choose material</p>
              <input class="osb" type="radio" name="materiale" id="osb" value="osb">
                  <label>OSB</label>
              <input class="fir" type="radio" name="materiale" id="fir" value="fir">
                  <label>FIR</label>
              <input class="mdf" type="radio" name="materiale" id="mdf" value="mdf">
                  <label>MDF</label>
              <input class="poplar" type="radio" name="materiale" id="poplar" value="poplar">
                  <label>POPLAR</label>
      </div>
      
      <div class="text">
          <div class="osb" style="display:none">OSB Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
          <div class="fir" style="display:none">FIR Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
          <div class="mdf" style="display:none">MDF Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
          <div class="poplar" style="display:none">POPOLAR Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</div>
      </div>
```

Note: You define `materialiText` but you never use it... If you keep it anyway, you should also change `materiale_value` to `materiale_value*2+1` on that line.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I understood why the live worked and here not. As @JstnPwll says it's better to do a warp of inputs. Which was already done in live. Thank you

Comment: no problem. And you are right, @JstnPwll's answer is better !

Answer (score 0):

You are close ... simply select the class-name instead of the index like that:

```js
document.querySelector('.text .' + materiale_valueName).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: yes, this also is an a good idea. Thank you